# PHP MySQL insert/update multiple rows at once

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have read this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255690/php-insert-a-variable-number-of-records-to-mysql-from-a-html-form#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255690/php-insert-a-variable-number-of-records-to-mysql-from-a-html-form#_=_)

But I cannot figure out how to apply this to a form with multiple inputs. 
I want these inputs to go into the same row (per array id).

My PHP renders the following HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 employee-container">
            <label for="visible-107">
                <img title="Jane Doe" src="/images/prof-pics/default.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Jane Doe">
            </label>
            <h4><input type="checkbox" name="visible[0]" id="visible-107"> <label for="visible-107">Jane Doe</label></h4>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Function</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="function[0]" id="function-107">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Order</span>
                <select class="form-control" name="order[0]" id="order-107">
                    <option value="">-- select one --</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            Description<br>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="description[0]" id="description-107"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 employee-container">
            <label for="visible-2"><img title="John Doe" src="/images/prof-pics/default.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="John Doe"></label>
            <h4><input type="checkbox" name="visible[1]" id="visible-2"> <label for="visible-2">John Doe</label></h4>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Function</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="function[1]" id="function-2">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Order</span>
                <select class="form-control" name="order[1]" id="order-2">
                    <option value="">-- select one --</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            Description<br>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="description[1]" id="description-2"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I iterate these arrays so that I can insert/update them as a row per array ID?

After implementing Nana Partykar's answer

```
function set_team($web_mysqli, $mysqli, $uid, $visible, $function, $order, $description, $action, $update_id = null ) {
    $number_empl = sizeof($function);

    for($i=0; $i<$number_empl; $i++) {
        $uid = $uid[$i];
        $visible = $visible[$i];
        $function = $function[$i];
        $order = $order[$i];
        $description = $description[$i];

        $name = get_full_name($mysqli, $uid, false);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO team (name, function, description, displayorder, visible) VALUES ('$name', '$function', '$description', '$order', '$visible')";
        $web_mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($web_mysqli));
    }

    $_SESSION['success'] = "Employee list website updated";
    header("Location: ".BASE_PATH."/includes/views/list-employees.php");
    exit();

if(isset($_POST['submit-btn'])) {
    set_team($web_mysqli, $mysqli, $_POST['uid'], $_POST['visible'], $_POST['function'], $_POST['order'], $_POST['description'], 'insert');
}
```

When I save only the first name is inserted into the table followed by 3 blank rows.

Comment: Is it fixed that you will use two times order[] or function[] or there is no limit. Just asking

Comment: No it isn't fixed, this is variable based on the number of records retrieved.

Comment: Ok. Wait for my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Need for `name[0]`,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="visible[0]" id="visible-107">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="function[0]" id="function-107">
<select class="form-control" name="order[0]" id="order-107">
<textarea class="form-control" name="description[0]" id="description-107"></textarea>
```

Make

```
<input type="checkbox" name="visible[]" id="visible-107">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="function[]" id="function-107">
<select class="form-control" name="order[]" id="order-107">
<textarea class="form-control" name="description[]" id="description-107"></textarea>
```

**SomePage.php (Submit Page)**

```
<?
extract($_POST);
$sizeOfFunc=sizeof($function);

for($i=0;$i<$sizeOfFunc;$i++)
{
    $Visible=$visible[$i];
    $Function=$function[$i];
    $Order=$order[$i];
    $Description=$description[$i];

    echo $Visible." ".$Function." ".$Order." ".$Description;

    //Use $Visible, $Function, $Order, $Description in your query
}

?>
```

**Updated Code**

> Don't use same variable name. Atleast change variable name.

This is wrong.

```
$uid = $uid[$i];
$visible = $visible[$i];
$function = $function[$i];
$order = $order[$i];
$description = $description[$i];
```

This is correct

```
$Uid = $uid[$i];
$Visible = $visible[$i];
$Function = $function[$i];
$Order = $order[$i];
$Description = $description[$i];
```

I've changed your code. Use the below code. It will work.

```
<?
function set_team($web_mysqli, $mysqli, $uid, $visible, $function, $order, $description, $action, $update_id = null ) {
    $number_empl = sizeof($function);

    for($i=0; $i<$number_empl; $i++) {
        $Uid = $uid[$i];
        $Visible = $visible[$i];
        $Function = $function[$i];
        $Order = $order[$i];
        $Description = $description[$i];

        $name = get_full_name($mysqli, $Uid, false);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO team (name, function, description, displayorder, visible) VALUES ('$name', '$Function', '$Description', '$Order', '$Visible')";
        $web_mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($web_mysqli));
    }

    $_SESSION['success'] = "Employee list website updated";
    header("Location: ".BASE_PATH."/includes/views/list-employees.php");
    exit();

if(isset($_POST['submit-btn'])) {
    set_team($web_mysqli, $mysqli, $_POST['uid'], $_POST['visible'], $_POST['function'], $_POST['order'], $_POST['description'], 'insert');
}
?>
```

I checked your code in my system after editing. It working fine.

```
<?

error_reporting(0);
extract($_POST);

echo $number_empl = sizeof($function);

for($i=0; $i<$number_empl; $i++) 
{
    $Visible = $visible[$i];
    $Function = $function[$i];
    $Order = $order[$i];
    $Description = $description[$i];
    $name="Just";

    echo $sql = "INSERT INTO team (name, function, description, displayorder, visible) VALUES ('$name', '$Function', '$Description', '$Order', '$Visible')"."<br>";

}
?>
```

Comment: shouldn't `$visible=visible[$i]` be `$visible=$visible[$i]`?

Comment: Yeah. Yeah. Typo mistake @MartijnICU.

Comment: I updated my code. @MartijnICU . Please have a look. And, let me know what happened ?

Comment: Line changed in the starting of page like `extract($_POST);
$sizeOfFunc=sizeof($function);`. Please have a look @MartijnICU

Comment: I've updated my answer @MartijnICU. Please have a look. It will work. Just because of simple issue it was not working. Now it will work.